# Cauchy Convergence for Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

We know that if $\sum a_{n}$ converges then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=0$. Using this fact, I need to prove that if $\sum a_{n}$ converges, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an integer K such that
$$
\left|\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n}\right| < \epsilon \quad \textrm{if} \quad k \ge K,
$$
that is,
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n} = 0.
$$
I know this is about the Cauchy Convergence Criterion, but I'm a bit confused with the premise and the form of the sum $|\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n}|$. This is usually expressed differently using n+p or something like that.

Comment: The sum is just the difference between the sum of the series and the $(k-1)$st partial sum, so it just expresses the definition:the sum of the series is the limit of the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: Thanks! I had understood it correctly then. Was just slightly confused with the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s_k:= \sum_{n=1}^k a_{n}$ and $b_k:=\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n}$. Then we have

$b_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}-s_{k-1} \to\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}=0 $ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! It seems my solution was pretty much correct after all. The premise and the different notation threw me off.